# Mathematica 13 doesn't show local documentation,

Tags: documentation

My **Mathematica 13** doesn't show local documentation, it includes just Web documentation. (Windows 11)
[image]

But **Mathematica 12.3** gives. How to enable local documentation to Mathematica 13?
[image]

---

**edit** (by Nasser)
Fyi, when installing, the choices given are

[image]

Make sure to select the one you want. First choice will download both Mathematica and full documentation to install locally

**end edit**

**edit**

If Mathematica 13 (incl. documentation) has to be installed on a business device, the license owner does not necessarily have admin rights. Now, if an admin installs Mathematica 13 on a Windows machine on behalf of the license owner, the documentation is installed in the App Data folder of the admin's user profile: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Wolfram Research\Documentation.en-us\13.0\Documentation (See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframSystemFileOrganization.html). The license owner can run Mathematica, however, the Documentation is only available online for him/her. One can, of course, move the documentation folder from the admin's user profile to the one of the license owner, however, Mathematica does ignore it. And there is no way to link the new location in the Option Inspector. As for the rest of the installation, the documentation should not be placed in the user profile, IMHO. But since Wolfram has decided to do so, it would be nice if one could at least manually relocate and link the local documentation directory.

**end edit**

Comment: Did you download the proper version? Starting with version 13.0, you can choose between "Mathematica (Web Documentation Only)" and "Mathematica + Documentation"

Comment: I think I didn't choose it. How can I do now instead of re-install?

Comment: If you did not download the documentation as part of your original installation (you might also just not have it installed, see @Konstantin's answer), there is a "Documentation Only (English)" download available that should install just the documentation

Comment: You must have chosen the online documentation version...those words written next to your three possible choices really did mean what they said! The DLM for the mathematica + documentation never worked for me, so I cannot confirm what Konstantin has written. I can, however, confirm that downloading the documentation only after that, as mentioned by Lukas Lang, does indeed install local documentation, albeit to your C drive, using the file mentioned by Konstantin; I was given no option to install elsewhere unlike the online documentation only version of mathematica.

Comment: So basically if you install web documentation you can't get help if you're not connected?  Seems kind of limiting to me.  Not sure why anyone would want this since easy to have 1 Tb disc drive.

Comment: @josh you can just download the documentation and the installer will integrate it with your mathematica installation. It is a very simple & smooth process. The only issue I find thus far is that I could not choose what disc drive the documentation was installed to.

Comment: I have no idea why WRI likes to complicate things like this. Just keep things simple. Put everything in one file. How hard can this be?  Why split things? internet is very fast these days and it takes only few minutes to download gigabytes of data.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In my installation package (for Windows), Local documentation is installed separately by `M-WIN-Documentation.en-us.msi` module

Comment: This msi does not allow run as admin and therefore the documentation will be installed into the user profile. That is it unavailable for other users. Docs requires  8+GB and have to be shared for all users but is not..

Answer (score 11):

According to this [blog post about launching v13](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2021/12/launching-version-13-0-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/), there should be a menu item `Install Local Documentation` for post-installing the documentation:

> If you change your mind later, you can always download and install
> the documentation using the `Install Local Documentation` item in the
> Help menu.

I do not know whether that works or not.

Comment: If that does not work, you can always just direct download the documentation & the installer will integrate it with your existing mathematica installation.

Comment: Downloaded and installed but it still doesn't show in the Documenation dropdown - only Web.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this post, it's very easy:   https://support.wolfram.com/56445