# How to integrate the Documentation with the Mathematica 13.1 installation?

Tags: documentation, installation

I believe I had chosen an installation of Mathematica 13.1 with the
Documentation. However, when I click on a command, it takes me to web page. That did not happen with previous version of Mathematica.

I read [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/260807/36858) to a similar question and launched M-WIN-Documentation.en-us-13.1.0-7806817.msi, but that process just exits without a trace just after "Gathering required information ...".

What can I do to get the Documentation locally, so that clicking on a command would open the corresponding help notebook on my computer?

**Added in response to closing the question:** I have contacted Wolfram support and received a response from them, which was utterly useless. What was really useful is the answer by Nasser on this page, which may be useful for other users as well. Therefore, I ask that the question be re-opened.

Comment: You should contact customer support if the installer is failing

Comment: @JasonB. : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You might want to make sure that Mathematica itself is not running when launching the documentation installer. I did the same thing and did not have an problem installing the documentation locally after installing mma.  windows 10.

Comment: @Nasser : Thank you very much. This solved the problem! Would you like to post your comment as a formal answer, so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before installing the documentation, make sure to close Mathematica itself if it is running.

This is what I did and had no problem installing the documentation after that.

Windows 10, V 13.1